# Use Session ID to verify user identity -- safe to do so?

Tags: php, mysql, session

I am writing a shopping cart program from scratch using PHP (Zend) and MySQL. Now I am implementing the guest shopping cart and I save the items in cart into a table in my database. Therefore each item in the table has the following fields:

item_id session_id some_other_details_fields

When a user visits the website I assign a session ID using session_start(), and if he or she adds something into cart, I insert a row into the table above.

So when users want to edit or remove something from their cart, they can do:

mydomain/cart/edit?item_id=XXX

and

mydomain/cart/delete?item_id=XXX

An obvious problem is that user can deliberately change XXX to access other's item info or remove items from other's cart. So I am thinking of adding mydomain/cart/edit?item_id=XXX&sess_id=YYY to verify if the sess_id YYY matches the session_id of item XXX in database.

I don't know if this is a good practice, and if using session ID to verify user identity would be sufficient. Any idea or reference on this would be highly appreciated.

EDIT:

1. I would like to save the items in cart for **as long as possible (e.g., up to 1 year)**, so I use session ID stored in cookies to identify users and save their items in cart in the database to make sure it will not be lost as long as the users do not clean up their cookies. **I was thinking sessions are usually used for storing user data for a shorter time, and may be less reliable than database, please let me know if this is wrong.**
2. For registered users I use a separate table for their carts and use user_id to identify them. If a guest registers I will move their items from the "guest cart table" to the "registered users cart table". Rather than using sessions which might be accidentally cleaned from time to time, I'd prefer to manually clean up the "guest cart table" just for peace of mind.
3. I am new in Zend so am not quite sure how to write this using Zend classes. So I decided to use php for these stuff.

Please correct me if I the things I do above are stupid. :)

Comment: Why not just store a users items in the session until they complete the order that way they can only edit items in their own session

Comment: Zend Framework will provide you with everything you need! Do not store it in the database.

Comment: If you're using a session, user will be able to access only his own cart. Or you're not understanding session well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't fully understand your design. Using a database suggests permanent storage, but binding the cart to a session means that users cannot register and keep their carts.

- If cart is just session data, it should get stored right into `$_SESSION`.
- If cart is permanent, the key should be the `user_id`.
- If you want a session cart that optionally gets saved into database when user registers, you can either use both approaches or go for database only. If you choose the latter, `user_id` would be optional  and `$_SESSION` would contain `cart_id`.

Additionally, transmitting the session ID in the URL (the default behaviour in earlier PHP versions) proved to be a wrong idea: it's too easy to give away your session data inadvertently (e.g. by just sending a link to a friend).

To sum up: there's normally no need to use the session ID.

---

I've just noticed your edit:

> I would like to save the items in cart for as long as possible (e.g.,
>   up to 1 year), so I use session ID stored in cookies to identify users
>   and save their items in cart in the database to make sure it will not
>   be lost as long as the users do not clean up their cookies.

So the shopping cart has actually nothing to do with the PHP session. Using the session ID as cart identifier unnecessarily links the whole session feature with your database cart and adds a lot of extra hassle for no benefit:

- You need to change the default session settings so session cookies persists across browser restarts.
- You increase the risk of session hijacking by reusing the same ID for months.

Are you sure you don't really mean **cookie** rather than **session**? It's just fine to generate a very long random alphanumeric identifier, store it into a cookie, and use it as secondary key for the database table.

---

**Followup questions**

> In terms of safety, would it be sufficient to generate just one long alphanumeric "GUID" for each guest and use that "GUID" to verify the identity when he or she comes back?

It doesn't need to global (the G in GUID) but I suppose it won't hurt. But you need to define "sufficient". Binding data to an IP address or User-Agent string makes it harder for attackers to gain access and makes it easier to user to lose his data. Using HTTPS-only makes it more secure you need to use HTTPS everywhere.

> To avoid "GUID" conflicts, is there a good point to start? I used session ID just because it will generate a "GUID" for me.

Sorry but the session ID is not a GUID: it's just a cryptographic hash with a random seed. But please think about it: it's extremely difficult to win a lottery that sells numbers from 00000 to 99999 (that's 1/100000 chances). If you generate a 32-character string with digits and 26 English letters you have 1 / 36^32 = 1.5787740357426709877210×10<sup>-50</sup>.

> For my case when shall I use sessions (as a best practice)? I'm kinda lost if this is not a good scenario to use sessions. Many thanks!

You're possibly using sessions already for user sign-in or order payment, for a pretty good reason: since HTTP is a stateless protocol, there's no other way to do it. Why is it so important to store the cart in session at any cost? ;-)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. For registered users I use a separate table for their carts and use user_id to identify them, just as the second approach you suggested. However for guests I would also like to save their items in cart for a long time (e.g., up to 1 year) so I am not sure if it is still a good idea to use $_SESSION. My hope is that as long as users don't clean up their cookies, any time they're back with the same computer/browser they would be able to see their items (the items on my site are highly customisable so it may be quite frustrating for guests to lose their items).

Comment: Thanks heaps for your prompt follow up. Yes I think I don't actually need a to start a PHP session here for guests. I have just some quick questions left: (1) In terms of safety, would it be sufficient to generate just one long alphanumeric "GUID" for each guest and use that "GUID" to verify the identity when he or she comes back? (2) To avoid "GUID" conflicts, is there a good point to start? I used session ID just because it will generate a "GUID" for me. (3) For my case when shall I use sessions (as a best practice)? I'm kinda lost if this is not a good scenario to use sessions. Many thanks!

Comment: Again, can't thank you more Álvaro (forgive me if I got it wrong) for your prompt answer. It's really clear and helpful. As in my case it is for items in guest shopping carts I'd assume using a UID stored in cookies would be enough. It would be great if you could also explain to me a bit on how a third party may be able to obtain that UID -- just to evaluate how safe this approach is, will not do this to others ;-) Anyway I will accept you answer and you have a lovely weekend.

Comment: How to grab the ID? Using non-HTTPS connections in a free wifi spot is a good starting point.

Answer (score 0):

Others told you to just use session, and generally this is the right way to do it. However, if you want a dual system "you can make an account, but you're not forced to do so", I see why you'd want to use a database (a single cart-saving system for both types of users, with the permanence needed by the registered ones).

So, if I understood your intention right, you want purchases in a database, related to the user ID. However, when the user chooses **not** to register and/or log in, you have a problem. In this case, I'd suggest saving some temporary user ID in a session, along with some flag (i.e. `$_SESSION["realUser"] = false;`) and using it as if it were real. To avoid conflicts, those temporary names should be unique. For example, they can start with a space character, which I assume is not allowed for the regular user IDs. Alternatively, you can use the pair of variables `$userId, $realUser` as a user identifier, and in that case `$userId` can be the same as the session ID.

However, carts connected to these temporary IDs will not last you a year. Once the session is deleted, the user will have no way to access that data. So, this data can be pruned after a much shorter period of time, while the data related to the regular users doesn't have to be pruned at all (so, they can find their cart even after a decade, although doing so doesn't make much sense to me).

If I understood you wrong and you don't want to mix registered users with the unregistered ones, just put all the data in the session and forget about databases for this, as others have suggested.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and it really makes much sense to me. I was wondering what would the temporary user ID saved in a session usually looks like? Is it going to be a long alphanumerical random string used as a unique identifier? I don't quite get how to "use it as if it were real" -- if I use it as a real one why would I still need the $SESSION["realUser"] flag? Here I assume the temporary user ID starts with a space character which guarantees it will conflict with real users. Many thanks!

Comment: If you just use session ID, it is (highly theoretically) possible that some user has the same username as some session ID, so you need to make that impossible. You can use `' '.session_id()`, but I feel it is better to use `session_id()` as a user ID and, at the same time, have a Boolean variable that tells you if the user is real or temporary. That way, you have a strong distinction between them, and tests don't involve analyzing the string, which is practical (especially in the database, where you can use conditions like `where not realUser`) and the code is more readable.

Comment: Thanks again on your prompt answer. Guess I got it now. Just one more quick question: so we are talking about a single "carts table" with each row as an item, from both guests and registered users?

Comment: Yes. That is the whole point of putting the temporary users' data (which usually belongs in session variables) into a database.